# Making a capturing group optional in a regex

Tags: php, regex

I have an automatically-generated email that I'm trying to parse out into fields for import into an application. I have a working regex for if all of the fields are present. However, this won't always be the case. Specifically, the phone number will sometimes be missing.

```
$regex = '/Bill\sTo:\s+([A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)\s.+[A-Z]{2}\s(\d{5})\s.*\s((?:\([2-9]\d{2}\)\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:\-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4})\s+([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\s+Ship\sTo:/s';
//                     ^       Name         ^    ^State ^  ^ Zip ^      ^                       Phone Number                            ^   ^                      Email                    ^

if (preg_match($regex, $content, $matches)) {
    $import = new ImportedEmail;

    $import->name = $matches[1];
    $import->zip = $matches[2];
    $import->phone = $matches[3];
    $import->email = $matches[4];

    // ...more processing code follows.
}
```

How can I get it to extract a phone number when it's present, but drop a NULL into `$import->phone` otherwise?

Note that "State" is in the regex just to help zero in on the location of the zip code.

Comment: `((?:\([2-9]\d{2}\)\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:\-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4})?` Try it this way (question mark at the end is added). But may be is it better to make generated emails more simple for better parsing ?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the content or format of the generated emails. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the capture group [a name](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) `(?P<name> ...)` and make it optional using the `?`.

I have prepared a simplified example. Let's say you have a string like:

```
name [age (optional)] message:
```

You can parse it with the following regex:

```
// Jon is 37 years old 
$str1 = 'jon 37 hello world';
// Jane does not tell about her age ;)
$str2 = 'jane foo bar';

preg_match('/(?P<name>[a-z]+ )?(?P<age>[0-9]+ )?(?P<message>.*)/', $str1, $m);    
echo $m['name'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $m['age'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $m['message'] . PHP_EOL;


preg_match('/(?P<name>[a-z]+ )?(?P<age>[0-9]+ )?(?P<message>.*)/', $str2, $m);    
echo $m['name'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $m['age'] . PHP_EOL; // index exists but is now empty
echo $m['message'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I think that does it! If I have any issues, then it'll be more along the lines of what happens to the surrounding whitespace when missing the phone number, but that's outside of the scope of this question. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! You can capture the surrounding whitespace also in an optional capturing group (anonymous, with a name)

Comment: Btw, I have simplified my example so that whitespace will not being handled.

Comment: The OP did not ask how to name a group. Your answer may be miss-interpreted as meaning the group needs to be named in order to make it optional, which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Put a ? directly after your phone number capturing group.